# SQL Server : MERGE causing cannot insert the value NULL into column

Tags: sql-server, merge, insert, null, sql-insert

I am doing a `MERGE` in SQL Server using the following code

```
MERGE INTO DW_Datawarehouse.[dbo].[DWF_WAREHOUSE] with (HOLDLOCK) AS target
USING #DataSource AS Source 
      ON target.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_NUM] = source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_NUM]
         AND target.DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_TYPE_CD = source.DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_TYPE_CD

WHEN MATCHED AND 
      (
      --all non-key fields, attributes and amounts
        source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_DESC] <> target.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_DESC]
        or source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_PICK_DATE_DAY] <> target.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_PICK_DATE_DAY]
        or source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_DAY_OF_WEEK_NUM] <> target.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_DAY_OF_WEEK_NUM]
        or source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_DIFF_QTY] <> target.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_DIFF_QTY]
        )
   THEN 
      UPDATE  
      SET target.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_DESC] = source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_DESC],
          target.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_PICK_DATE_DAY] = source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_PICK_DATE_DAY],
          target.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_DAY_OF_WEEK_NUM] = source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_DAY_OF_WEEK_NUM],
          target.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_DIFF_QTY] = source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_DIFF_QTY]

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_DESC], [DWF_WAREHOUSE_PICK_DATE_DAY],
            [DWF_WAREHOUSE_DAY_OF_WEEK_NUM], [DWF_WAREHOUSE_DIFF_QTY])
    VALUES (source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_DESC], source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_PICK_DATE_DAY],
            source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_DAY_OF_WEEK_NUM], source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_DIFF_QTY])

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE;
```

I am getting the error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_NUM',
> table 'DW_Datawarehouse.dbo.DWF_WAREHOUSE'; column does not allow
> nulls. UPDATE fails.

How would I modify my `MERGE` code to avoid this error?

Comment: Do you have `trigger` on `DWF_WAREHOUSE` table. Your current `Merge` query will not produce this error

Comment: It means that you need to specify a value for the column `DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_NUM`. Your `INSERT` statement does not include this column.

Answer (score 0):

It  sound like there is null of DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_NUM in data Source.
you can change data source to

```
SELECT * FROM #DataSource AS WHERE DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_NUM IS NOT NULL
```

Example:

```
MERGE INTO DW_Datawarehouse.[dbo].[DWF_WAREHOUSE] with (HOLDLOCK) as target
  USING
(SELECT * FROM #DataSource AS WHERE DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_NUM IS NOT NULL)AS Source

  ON target.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_NUM] = source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_NUM]
  AND target.DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_TYPE_CD = source.DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_TYPE_CD

WHEN MATCHED AND 
  (
  --all non-key fields, attributes and amounts
    source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_DESC] <> target.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_DESC]
    or source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_PICK_DATE_DAY] <> target.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_PICK_DATE_DAY]
    or source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_DAY_OF_WEEK_NUM] <> target.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_DAY_OF_WEEK_NUM]
    or source.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_DIFF_QTY] <> target.[DWF_WAREHOUSE_DIFF_QTY]
    )
.....
```